# iphone configuration utility 3.3 can't install configurations

Tags: iphone, ios

I can't install configuration profiles with the iPhone Configuration Utility on iPads etc for enterprise deployment. I can still however install apps. Problem is only with the configuration profiles. The Install button appears but it just doesn't do the install. This was fine before Lion. And I am using iPhone Configuration Utility 3.4. I have enabled root user as discussed in previous post, but when I log in again, I can't install profiles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple Enterprise Support just figured this out for me.

Clean install of app.
Go to user directory/Library/preferences/iPhoneConfigurationUtility

go to preferences associated with iPhoneConfigurationUtility com.apple.iPhoneConfigurationUtility etc.
You will see plists.

Delete them.

Restart or reinstall.

Fixed.

Comment: Great!! Works For me too..:)